# OpenCV Camera calibration from a set of 3d and corresponding 2d points

Tags: unity-game-engine, opencv, camera-calibration

I am new to here and I get some troubles with calibration.

I am going to synthesize frames in Unity3D as dataset(Like MultiviewX ) for further CNN trainning.
For the first step, I need to calibrate the camera to get the intrinsics and extrinsics of the camera. Yes, there are some mathmatcial methods to get the intrinsics and the extrinsics. However, it could be better if I can get the result from OpenCV.

To finish the calibration, I setup the scene with many points(like figure below). I can get the 3D world position(by gameobject.transform.position)and the 2D screen position(by camera.worldToScreen()) of the generated green point.

Here is the data: https://github.com/TsingLoo/MultiviewX_FYP/tree/master/cali

I think that with corresponding 3D-2D point pairs, by using

```
size = (1920,1080)
points_2d = np.loadtxt(f'calib/Camera{cam + 1}.txt')
points_3d = np.loadtxt(f'calib/Camera{cam + 1}_3D.txt')

points_2d = np.concatenate(points_2d, axis=0).reshape([1, -1, 2]).astype('float32')
points_3d = np.concatenate(points_3d, axis=0).reshape([1, -1, 3]).astype('float32')

cameraMatrix = cv2.initCameraMatrix2D(points_3d, points_2d, size, 1)
```

and

```
retval, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvecs, tvecs = \
    cv2.calibrateCamera(points_3d, points_2d, size, cameraMatrix, None,flags = cv2.CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS)
```

could get the correct calibration(fx = fy = 935f). However, the result varies a lot.

I want to get the correct calibration(both intrinsics and extrinsics) result like this:  https://github.com/hou-yz/MultiviewX/tree/master/calibrations

I noticed that the OpenCV document for **cv2.calibrateCamera** mentions that Z value should be zero. I have tried that and still failed to get the correct calibration.

Comment: Afair, only for the initial intrinsics guess you need z=0 points

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Do you mean I should ensure that the Z value of points_3d taken by cv2.initCameraMatrix2D be zero? The points_3d taken by cv2.calibrateCamera have no constraint even when flag cv2.CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS is marked?

Comment: It seems that corresponding points from the single view can not accomplish the calibration.
I fix this problem by using this: [CalibrateTool](http://www.tsingloo.com/2023/03/01/0a2bf39019914a06954a4506b9f0ca37/).